# Node Js wrong global NODE PATH

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I'm having problem with modules. Every time i use any downloaded module i get that error:(Express for example)

```
Cannot find package 'express' imported from (folder of my app)
```

Also i tried to install modules to my local app folder, but it just doesn't see them.
It tries to find them in wrong global path

```
user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Typescript/4.8/node_modules
```

But my installation path is

```
user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules
```

I tried to change NODE_PATH env variable, and also npm installation prefix
And I tried to reinstall Node.js

But none of this helped me

Comment: You don't have to point to the dir, just "import express from express"

Comment: @Moses, I'm using "import express from "express" already. And npm tries to find it in wrong folder.

Comment: check and confirm NODE_PATH is pointing to the right directory